# What are good ways to preset plotting options for ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im having a bunch of lengthy repetitive ggplot2 instructions throughout a file. So far i've been using variables control preset values keeping graphs uniform, having the configuration in one spot (e.g. to change the color of all graphs).

What i'm really looking for is a good way to preset those instructions so i don't have to write the statements all over. As an example, i define somewhere top in the file:

```
OPTAX=theme_text(angle=30, hjust=1, vjust=1, size=8)
```

Where the plot statements is, i use

```
P<-ggplot(
       data=MYDATA,
       aes(x=Topics, y=value, fill=variable)) +
       ....
       opts(axis.text.x=OPTAX)
)
```

I would like to avoid writing the `axis.text.x=MYVAR` part and write something like

```
... + opts(MYOPTS) + ...
```

or avoid the opts statement at all and write

```
... + ALLMYOPTS + ...
```

so all my options are predefined in one statement.

As a second thing it would be good to override the statement. Something like

```
opts(MYOPTS, axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=60)
```

would be great, so i can keep the preset but still use custom options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
ALLMYOPTS <- opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=30, hjust=1, vjust=1, size=8))
P + ALLMYOPTS
```

Comment: Thank you. This works quite and ggplot accepts the last option as the valid one, so it's easily possible to override them.

Answer (score 11):

You can wrap up all sorts of ggplot configuration - not just `opts` - and apply it to multiple graphs, by using a list:

```
myPrettyOptions = list(
   opts(axis.text.x=OPTAX),
   facet_wrap(~Topic),
   limits(x=c(1,2)),
   scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0,5))
)
```

Then use this in multiple locations: (think of the space you will save!):

```
ggplot(blah) + myPrettyOptions
# in the second plot we can override the options:
ggplot(foo) + myPrettyOptions + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=60)
```

You can take this even further and prepare everything except the data:

```
graphtemplate = ggplot(blah) + myPrettyOptions
graphtemplate %+% data1
graphtemplate %+% data2
```

Note the use of the `%+%` operator.

Comment: What does the `%+%` operator do? (these `%...%` things are impossible to google and I can't find `%+%` in the R manual)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. FYI you can get help for these operators via `?\`%+%\`` and search google for odd characters with http://www.symbolhound.com/

Comment: `opts` is now deprecated in `ggplot2`: "use 'theme' instead"

Answer (score 4):

An even more terse approach involves using the theme_update, theme_get, and theme_set methods.

```
old.theme <- theme_update(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=30, hjust=1, vjust=1, size=8))
qplot(1,1)
```

If you want to revert to the old theme use, simply,

```
theme_set(old.theme)
qplot(1,1)
```

Comment: With the latest `ggplot2` the above solution worked well with `element_text()` instead of `theme_text()`

Answer (score 0):

Put every parameter in an object first, ex:

```
 a<- theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
    b<- theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#e4e4e4")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, size=rel(1.5)))+ theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.5))) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.5)))+ theme(legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5), face = "italic")) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5))) + theme(axis.text = element_text(size=rel(1.0)))
    c<- theme(axis.line.x=element_line(size=0.5, colour="black"))
    d<- theme(axis.line.y=element_line(size=0.5, colour="black"))
    e<- theme(legend.box.just = c("top"), legend.position="bottom",legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.direction="vertical", legend.box="horizontal") + theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
    f<- ggplot(blah) + a +b +c +d +e
    f
```